# Does the position of the kipa change as the man changes his orientation with respect to the ground?

Tags: kippa-yarmulka

Is the correct position for the kipa always above the head or does it change as you change positions? For example if you hang upside down does the kipa still need to be on "top" of your head or should you move it to the side (back of the head, or chin)? How about when you lay down on your back or belly?

Question Motivation: When you lie down in bed and need to recite a blessing, do you need to reposition the kippah or it's fine in the regular position - the place it would be have been had you been standing and it would be above your head.

Comment: Logic would imply that it is clothing. just as a shirt and pants stay were they belong, a kipa stays on the head. However, I have no source for this.

Comment: I don't know what to make of this. Is this a "Purim" question? Isn't the pupose of the kippa to specifically cover your **head** and not some other part of the body?

Comment: Ani Yodea, could you edit in your motivation for asking?  Are you assuming that the kippah should remain between the head and heaven?

Answer (score 2):

No you would not need to cover any other part of the body - the rule of kippah is specifically in terms of covering the head. The phrase that is used to describe the minhag is "גילוי הראש" to have your HEAD uncovered. 
See קידושיו לא עמוד א ,רמבם משנה תורה הלכות דעות פרק ה הלכה ו, שולחן ערוך אורח חיים סימן ב סעיף ו, שולחן ערוך אורח חיים סימן צא סעיף ג, and משנה ברורה סימן ב סעיף קטן יא among other places where the term is used.

In addition the last source quoted discusses whether one is required to cover ones head when one is sleeping. Assuming you don't sleep standing up this would be a clear example where one is potentially required to cover the HEAD and not another part of the body (either back or belly depending on whether you sleep on your belly or back...)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for providing this answer. Consider taking the following short [tour of the site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more. Hope you stick around.

Comment: What is meant by covering the head if you are upside down?

Comment: This answer is answering a different question... I am asking if you should move your kippah to a different location ON YOUR HEAD - not your body.